# How to verify audio/video streams in automation

Tags: windows, selenium, audio, video

I am having a screen sharing application (WebRTC). One user wants to share his screen with another user. Like one application running on User 1 machine and another application running on User 2 machine. User 1 wants to share his screen, now how to verify on User 2 that he is receiving User 1's audio and video stream via automation. 
I am using Selenium to launch the application on Chrome browser but how will I verify the audio/video codecs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use [testrtc.com](https://testrtc.com).

We offer a testing services for WebRTC that make use of Selenium and solve the types of problems you're having.

Comment: Will see to it @ Tsahi. Thanks for sharing information

Answer (score 1):

The WebRTC samples at https://github.com/webrtc/samples contain quite a bit of Selenium testing examples -- look for files named test.js.

See https://blog.andyet.com/2015/07/28/selenium-travis-webrtc for a short description of how this works.

Testing screen sharing is somewhat tricky since currently, you can't combine screen sharing and fake audio devices :-(

Comment: Hi @Philipp Thanks for your answer. I was able to see good examples ! In my case i need to verify whether the fakecam video received on other user end.  My exact scenario is to create a video conference room with three participants. All three will login from an chrome application on three different machines and each participant will be able to see all two participants feed including their own. In this case how do we verify audio/video feed ? I need to automate the above scenario using selenium

Comment: https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/test/selenium/three.js shows a test for that if you want to DIY. It verifies that the P2P connection can be established, you'll have to use the getStats API to check for actual audio/video traffic.. But as Tsahi points out, testrtc.com does a lot of the lifting for you.